# How to find radius of a circle inscribed in a quadrilateral, given its sides?

Tags: geometry

I came across this problem as I was preparing for an olympiad and it totally stumped me out. Can anyone please help me to solve it... Here it is:

In a quadrilateral $ABCD$, it is given that $AB = AD = 13$, $BC = CD = 20$, $BD = 24$. If $r$ is the radius of a circle inscribed in the quadrilateral, then what is the integer closest to $r$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral#Inradius) and you can use the formula.

Comment: Thank you for the link. :-)

Comment: This is a very nice problem in geometry, the kind of problems i always enjoyed in my youth, this kind of mathematics determined me to chose mathematics and stay with it as long as i can. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:*

According to the Wikipedia page, the inradius of a tangential quadrilateral is:

$$r = \frac{K}{s}$$

where $K$ is the quadrilateral's area and $s$ is the semiperimeter, which is $\frac{13+13+20+20}{2} = 33$.

To find the area, split the quadrilateral into two smaller triangles, such as $\Delta ABD$ and $\Delta BDC$. Then you can apply Heron's formula on each of them:

$$\text{Area} = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

where $a,b,c$ are the sides of the triangles.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the proof for the formula. Is this fine with you?

Comment: I could have only used Heron's formula if I had the length of the diagonal with me, which I don't. So, finding the area still stays a problem

Comment: You don't actually need the diagonal. You can split the quadrilateral by the side $BD$, which is given in the question.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. Missed that one.

Comment: Thanks @TobyMak

Answer (score 4):

Note that the triangles $\Delta ABD$ and $\Delta CBD$ are isosceles in $A$ and $C$. This implies that the side bisector of the given diagonal $BD$ is also the median, and angle bisector in the two triangles. It follows that the given quadrilateral has perpendicular diagonals $AC$, $BD$, they intersect in $O$, the mid point of the segment $BD$. Now we consider the triangles $\Delta AOB$ and $\Delta COB$, both with a right angle in $O$.

- The first triangle has the known sides $13$, $12$, so $AO=5$.
- The second triangle has the known sides $20$, $12$, so $CO=16$.

So the diagonals of the triangle are $BD=24$, and $AC=AO+OC=5+16=21$.

The area of the quadrilateral is half of the area of the rectangle with sides parallel to the diagonals $AC,BD$, where the sides are passing through $A,B,C,D$, so it is $\frac 12 24\cdot 21=12\cdot 21=252$.

Let now $K\in AC$ be the center of the circle which is tangent to all sides. 
Let $r$ be the radius of this circle. We consider the four triangles built with $K$ as one vertex, and with one side of the quadrilateral, then compute their areas. We obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
252 
&=\operatorname{Area}(ABCD)
\\
&=
\operatorname{Area}(\Delta KAB) +
\operatorname{Area}(\Delta KBC) +
\operatorname{Area}(\Delta KCD) +
\operatorname{Area}(\Delta KDA) 
\\
&=\frac 12 r(AB+BC+CD+DA)
\\
&=r(AB+BC)
\\
&=33r
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This leads to $r=252/33=7.63636363\dots$ .

The closest integer is $8$.

---

EDIT: Added picture:

[image: Added picture of the quadrilateral with sides 13, 13, 20, 20, and diagonals 24, and 5+16=21]

Comment: Your answer is correct and I liked your effort. ==|:-)

Comment: +1 You have a nice method for computing the area in two different ways, and using that to calculate $r$.